# Google Script Need - Auto email request to update password to users every 90 days

Tags: gwt, google-apps-script, google-apps

Is it possible to create a script that would require users within a domain to auto update their password every 90 days? 
This would be for a Super Admin on Google Apps, for a company of 30 employees. 
It would be great if an email can automatically be generated to notify the users that this must be done.
Im open to ideas / suggestions

Comment: Are you looking at only sending out an email or forcing users to update their passwords as well?

Comment: see if this covers your scenario https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reseller/v1/reference/